# Get specific data from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an auto-complete input that I want to get the value from it ,
I log the data and I got this ,
How I can get any attribute that I want like value or auto focus.

this is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autocomplete').val();
});
```

I have some context data and the data that I need have this property path

```
.context.activeElement.value
```

how I should call this part?
This image shows my data that I want export some thing form it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$("#id").attr("attr-name")
```

Comment: Thanks, I update my question that make my goal clerify

Comment: I add an image I hope it help you to got my goal

Comment: Could you add the 'console.log()' line too? It seems that there is no selector match with your query

Comment: I just test it in console window as you can see in the 3 line first

Comment: I think to understand your issue, you call 'document.ready()' function on a document already ready.

Comment: So try just to use: $("#autocomplete").Val()